# ¿Cómo establecer rutas amigables con php?

Tags: php, html, rutas

Tengo un proyecto que quiero poner rutas amigables.
Ejemplo:
Actualmente tengo pongo esta ruta:
http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacion/index.php

Pero quiero convertirla en una ruta amigable, es decir:
http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacion/index/

Tengo ya algo realizado, pero resulta que tengo que poner la / despues del index, ya que si no la pongo, sale error 404

Cree un .htaccess para realizar esto, y en mi codigo tengo esto:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Rewriterule ^index/$ index.php
Rewriterule ^default/$ default.php
RewriteRule ^usuarios/editUsuario/([0-9]+)$ usuarios/editUsuario.php?id_u=$1
```

Pero al hacer algunos links ya sea de etiquetas  o archivos css, la ruta de estos me marca como si estuviera adentro del index, Alguna idea de como resolverlo? Muchas gracias

Comment: Pudiste utilizar las reglas que puse en la respuesta? Te resulto útil? Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Yo ocupo este codigo, espero te ayude.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente su funcionamiento. Lee [answer].

Answer (score 0):

El **.htaccess** deberías tenerlo con lo siguiente :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/$2.php [QSA]
```

lo que coloques antes y después de la  / :

```
^(.*)/(.*) # tener en cuenta estas expresiones regulares
```

devolverá el resultado que tenga de tu sitio en:

```
http://localhost:82/$1/$2.php
```

**Ejemplo 1:**

```
http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacion/index/
```

Ira a la ruta:

```
http://localhost:82/admonCapacitacion/index.php
```

**Voy a un segundo ejemplo mas desarrollado:**

La expresión regular -> (.*) tiene la regla para ir a una variable -> $1

Vamos a una caso mas extenso

```
(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
```

Ingresando a la URL: (este caso es excesivamente largo y con una cantidad de variables mayor. Es solo a modo educativo.

```
miweb.com/$var1/$var2/$var3/$var4/$var5/$var6/$var7/$var8/
```

Una URL amigable podría verse así:

```
miweb.com/tienda/electronicos/smart/generico/80pulgadas/4hdmi/negro/ambient/
```

En este ejemplo, la URL amigable tiene las reglas para ir al siguiente URL:

```
miweb.com/$1.php?rubro=$2&tipo=$3&marca=$4&pulgadas=$5&filtro1=$6&filtro2=$7&filtro3=$8
```

Tener en cuenta que en este caso esta buscando la página **tienda.php** la cual tiene que existir sino dará error.

**El .htaccess quedaría así:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /$1.php?rubro=$2&tipo=$3&marca=$4&pulgadas=$5&filtro1=$6&filtro2=$7&filtro2=$8 [QSA]
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad. Saludos.

Comment: Hola, apenas pude ver tu respuesta. Gracias por tu aportación. Creo que estoy poniendo mal el codigo, comentas que lo que ponga antes de / pero ejemplo pongo: RewriteRule ^(.*)cat_usuarios.php/(.*)$ /$1/$2.php [QSA] y no me encuentra la pag. Saludos!

Comment: Deberías pasar la URL para ver como quedo armada. Y luego ver si existe el destino hacia donde va. Que erro esta apreciando?

Comment: @juliofernandez ahora hice una actualización con un ejemplo mas extenso y quizá sea mas claro. Saludos.